# Attaching PR2 Gripper to UR10 robot

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello

I am just starting with gazebo, and I have a problem with attaching the PR2 Gripper to the UR10 robot. I created the model.config and ur10PR2.sdf according to this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=attach_gripper&cat=build_robot). The problem is that it's not loading it. I get "unable to load file" and "parse as old deprecated model file failed" in the terminal. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Here are the two files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model>
  <name>Universal Robotics UR10 robot arm with PR2 gripper</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <sdf version='1.4'>ur10PR2.sdf</sdf>

  <author>
    <name>Kelsey Hawkins</name>
    <email>kphawkins@gatech.edu</email>
  </author>

  <description>
    The UR10 robot arm model built by Kelsey Hawkins. With PR2 gripper attached
    Taken from git@github.com:ros-industrial/universal_robot.git for Gazebo testing and integration purposes.
  </description>
</model>
```

And the sdf file:

```
<xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
    <model name="ur10_pr2">

        <include>
            <uri>model://ur10</uri>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>

        <include>
            <uri>model://pr2_gripper</uri>
            <pose>1.1843 0.163941 0.0116 3.141591 0 3.141591</pose>
        </include>

        <joint name="arm_gripper_joint" type="revolute">
            <parent>ur10::wrist3</parent>
            <child>pr2_gripper::r_wrist_roll_link</child>
            <axis>
                <limit>
                    <lower>0</lower>
                    <upper>0</upper>
                </limit>
                <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
            </axis>
        </joint>
    </model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8049/attaching-pr2-gripper-to-ur10-robot/) by [Martin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1116/martin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The error is because you forgot the question mark on the xml tag on the sdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1116/martin/) on 2015-02-22**:
Thanks for the quick reply. Such a stupid error.